# Yesod - function for getting the value of an Entity

Tags: haskell, yesod

take a look:

```
myEntity :: Entity Post
myEntity = ...

myValue :: Entity Post -> Post
myValue = <someFunction>

myKey :: Entity Post -> PostId
myKey = <someOtherFunction>
```

Does `someFunction` and `someOtherFunction` exist in yesod or do I need to create them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have `Entity key val`, then for `val`

```
> :t entityVal
entityVal :: Entity record -> record
> :i entityVal
type role Entity nominal
data Entity record where
  Entity :: PersistEntity record =>
            (Key record) -> record -> Entity record
        -- Defined in ‘persistent-2.2.1:Database.Persist.Class.PersistEntity’
```

or for `key`

```
> :t entityKey
entityKey :: Entity record -> Key record
> :i entityKey
type role Entity nominal
data Entity record where
  Entity :: PersistEntity record =>
            (Key record) -> record -> Entity record
        -- Defined in ‘persistent-2.2.1:Database.Persist.Class.PersistEntity’
```

or for both you can use pattern matching, e.g.

```
> let getR (Entity k v) = (k , v)
> :t getR
getR :: Entity t -> (Key t, t)
```

Comment: Do you know how to set `hoogle` to be used from `stack ghci` inside my project, to easily found out those functions by querying in there? For instance: `:hoogle Entity a b -> b`

Comment: @FtheBuilder you can install hoogle command line api by `stack install hoogle` and run it from ghci by `:!hoogle YOUR_QUERY`, while it has to cache the whole hackage and keep its database up-to-date may be very painful depends on your network condition. If you use duckduckgo as your default search engine then you can do it in your browser's search bar: `!hoogle YOUR_QUERY` or `!hayoo YOUR_QUERY` for more hits.

Comment: @zakyggaps when I try from terminal `hoogle [a] -> a` it works but doesn't bring a single line...

Comment: @FtheBuilder did you run `hoogle data` in advance?

Comment: @zakyggaps still nothing appear.

Comment: @FtheBuilder I guess you now have a file `a` in working directory? Does `hoogle "[a] -> a"` return anything?

Comment: @zakyggaps now it brought results